# Unexpected field while uploading video using angular8, nodejs and multer

Tags: node.js, angular8, multer, image-upload, video-upload

I am uploading image and video, working fine when uploading image but getting error as 'Unexpected field' while uploading video
I have mentioned my source code for reference

Please help me, Thanks in advance

```
 <input id="cctv_image1" name="cctv_image1" type="file" class="dropify"
                                    data-default-file="" data-show-errors="true"
                                    data-allowed-file-extensions="jpeg jpg png gif" formControlName="image"
                                    (change)="selectImage($event)">

 <input autocomplete="off" type="file" id="cctv_image3" name="cctv_image3" multiple
                                    type="file" accept=".mp4" class="dropify" data-default-file=""
                                    data-allowed-file-extensions="mp4" formControlName="video"
                                    (change)="selectVideo($event)">

selectImage(event) {
    this.image = event['target']['files'][0];
  }

  selectVideo(event) {
    this.video = event['target']['files'][0];
  }


const postData = new FormData();
 if (this.video) {
      console.log('video_found');
      postData.append('video', noticeData.video);
    }
postData.append('image', noticeData.image);

router.post('/create-notice', middleware.checkToken, multer({storage: image}).single('image'), multer({storage: video}).single('video'), complaintController.createNotice);

onst image = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "../src/assets/public/photo");
  },
  filename : (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.' + ext);
  }
});

const video = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "../src/assets/public/video");
  },
  filename : (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = VIDEO_MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    console.log(ext); return;
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.' + ext);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'multiple' from input declaration in HTML either add 'array' to multer call.

Comment: I removed multiple but getting same error as 'Unexpected field'